# What should be the Prisma database URL for an mssql running in a container on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, prisma

I have a container 'sql1' running sqlserver from which I can query using:

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U SA -P ""

Should the URL for prisma from the Ubuntu bash shell be this:

DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://sql1:1433;database=trinity;user=SA;password=;encrypt=true"

OR more like the standard one :
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://SA:@sql1:1433/trinity"

Comment: The container name, `sql1`, will only be resolvable from other containers within the same Docker composition. If you're needing a process on the Docker host to connect then have you tried to use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead?

Comment: Ok, I've downloaded sql server into a W11 PC. I have SSMS working. I'm trying: Using integrated security (Windows only)
The following example uses the currently logged in Windows user to log in to Microsoft SQL Server:
sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=sample;integratedSecurity=true;trustServer=true;" \\Still get Error creating a database connection

Comment: sp@DESKTOP-BKF6MGC:/mnt/c/Users/steph/assignar$ npx prisma db pull
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Environment variables loaded from .env
Datasource "db": SQL Server database

× Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma\schema.prisma

Error: Error creating a database connection.

Comment: #DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=trinity;user={DESKTOP-BKF6MGC\steph};"#DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=trinity;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=trinity;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"

Comment: You seem to be using database names such as `sample` and `trinity` in your connection strings. Have you created any of these databases on the target SQL Server instance yet? Have you created Windows Logon(s) inside SQL Server yet for the accounts under which these `integrated security` connections are executing? Are the Windows Logon(s) mapped to database users in the named databases?

Comment: When trying to diagnose login failures it's best to connect to the target SQL Server instance with SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and check what's happening in the Management > SQL Server Logs node. Look for the Error 18456 (Login failure) events, take note of the `State` number(s) that they report, and compare them against the `State` numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual cause(s) of login failure.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning.  "Are the Windows Logon(s) mapped to database users in the named databases?" NO they were not !!